# Form not saving into database when attaching a photo in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

So I am using paperclip for my project. For my form, I have a title and text field which take in strings and a file field for attaching photos. When I submit the form with a title and text but no photo, it saves perfectly fine. However, when I also attach a file, it doesn't save at all.

I'm assuming it's not saving, because it doesn't show up when I list out all the articles through the index page.

Edit: So I figured out it was something to do with the paperclip validation. When I changed it so it doesn't check for any validations, it works fine.

So, why isn't it working with this validation: validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]

I also changed "image" to "photo" since that's what I named it. Also, I'm uploading jpg's

Comment: Can you include the code for the Model you are trying to save, as well as the code of the form?

Comment: Also look in the logs. What error do you get.  My guess is strong params violation or else a validation that is failing. But as @dannemanne said please post code for model, form , and controller action. As well as any logs.